# How to I get back into psql shell on windows?

Tags: windows, postgresql

I have been trying to get back into my Postgresql shell but I couldn't. Whenever I try Psql command it doesn't recognize it.

[image]

Comment: Well, you need to run `psql.exe` - if "*it doesn't recognize it*", you need to provide the full path to the exe. But that has nothing to do with Postgres. That's basic Windows command line knowledge

Comment: Shouldn't there be an error message?  I don't know what that image represents.  I've not seen CMD produce something that looks like that (an image of a text shell with some icon image embedded into it), nor "Windows Exploder" either.